# Get access to currently bound objects in eval

Tags: racket, eval

## Caveat

I know what I'm going to be asking here is generally evil. I am asking specifically because I want to make tests to ensure my static analysis works correctly even if a user does call eval (what this question is about). To read more on this, check out [On eval in dynamic languages generally and in Racket specifically](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html)

## Question

In many other dynamic languages, I can use `eval` to modify the state of my current environment. I would like to do something similar to this in Racket. For example, I would like to write something like:

```
#lang racket
(define x 5)
(eval '(set! x 6))
(displayln x)
```

And have `x` be set to `6`. Is something like this possible to do in Racket?

Comment: From the question it's not exactly clear what the "this" is in "even if a user does this". Is the sample code code you want to implement or data that you receive from the user?

Comment: Fair, I've updated the caveat to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using Namespace Anchors. Specifically, you want [`define-namespace-anchor`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=namespace-anchor-%3Enamespace#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define-namespace-anchor%29%29) and [`namespace-anchor->namespace`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=namespace-anchor-%3Enamespace#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._namespace-anchor-~3enamespace%29%29).

Specifically, you use `define-namespace-anchor` in the code where you would like to have your syntax objects bound. And you use `namespace-anchor->namespace` to turn that into a namespace, which can either be parmeterized to `current-namespace`, or just passed into eval directly.

Your code would look something like this:

```
#lang racket
(define-namespace-anchor foo)
(define x 5)
(eval '(set! x 6) (namespace-anchor->namespace foo))
(displayln x)
```

Will give you the following error:

```
. set!: assignment disallowed;
 cannot modify a constant
  constant: x
```

This is actually because the compiler is setting `x` to be a static variable because it thinks it will never get mutated. (And thus can be optimized in many places.)

You can convince the compiler that it is going to be mutated by statically calling `set!` once.

```
#lang racket
(define-namespace-anchor foo)
(define x (void))
(set! x 5)
(eval '(set! x 6) (namespace-anchor->namespace foo))
(displayln x)
```

This will print out `6`, which is what you would expect.

Although note that this is only true for things such as `set!`. It doesn't mean that `x` itself will never be mutated. For example, we could have used a `box`, `unbox` and `set-box!`

```
#lang racket
(define-namespace-anchor foo)
(define x (box 5))
(eval '(set-box! x 6) (namespace-anchor->namespace foo))
(displayln (unbox x))
```

This also holds true for any data structure that is mutable, such as vectors, mutable lists, or mutable hash tables.

Comment: Very possibly. I honestly never really understood fully when it should be one or the other.